# Cannot access "this" keyword in Javascript function when calling a nested inline function?

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet

I'm using leaflet to build custom styles for my different map features in Angular.

```
export class MapComponent  {
    protected _map: Map;           // leaflet map
    public pads: string[] = [];

.
.
.
.

    L.geoJSON(geojsonFeature, {
        onEachFeature: this.onEachFeature,
        style: function (layer, feature, pads) {
            return {color: "#FFF"}
        }

    }).addTo(this._map);
```

In the style: call, I pass in `pads` as a parameter, but it's undefined within the function

if I make the function no longer in-line,

```
    styler(feature, layer) {
       console.log(this.pads);
    }
```

Then update the call to:

```
    L.geoJSON(geojsonFeature, {
        onEachFeature: this.onEachFeature,
        style: this.styler;
        }

    }).addTo(this._map);
```

I cannot access the `this` keyword. I'm incredibly confused by the scoping of how all of this is interacting. I need to access my `pads` array from either an inline or outside function.

Comment: *"I pass in pads as a parameter"* No you are not.  You are *defining* that the function has a third parameter called `pads`. But you are *not calling* the function at that moment, and I doubt that it's you who calls the function, so you cannot *pass* any additional arguments to it.

Comment: Makes sense. I am not calling this function. What are my options for accessing this variable?

Comment: See the duplicate. The short answer is: `style: this.styler.bind(this)`.

Comment: Informative post, thanks. This is working.